# Create full Representation of JSON

Tags: json, representation

I am trying to create a full JSON representation of Scan:

```
Scan  
Id: 3  
article: 3  
user: 1  
created_at: 2015-05-04  
is_purchased: true  

Article  
id: 3  
title: Lelles bread  
brand: Bear  
quantity: 5.243  
entity: oz  
created_at: 2014-04-21  

User  
id: 1  
firstName: Frans  
lastName: Anderson  
userName: FRAN  
mail: anderson@me.om
```

**Is this JSON representation correct?**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "article": [
        {
            ”id”: 3,
            ”title”: ”LellesBread”,
            ”brand”: ”Bear”,
            ”quantity”: 5.243,
            ”entity: ”oz”,
            ”created_at”: ”2014-04-21”
        }
        {
            ”id”: 3,
            ”title”: ”LellesBread”,
            ”brand”: ”Bear”,
            ”quantity”: 5.243,
            ”entity: ”oz”,
            ”created_at”: ”2014-04-21”
        }
        {
            ”id”: 3,
            ”title”: ”LellesBread”,
            ”brand”: ”Bear”,
            ”quantity”: 5.243,
            ”entity: ”oz”,
            ”created_at”: ”2014-04-21”
        }
    ]
   "user": {
        ”id”: 1,
        ”firstName”: ”Frans”,
        ”lastName”: ”Anderson”,
        ”UserName”: ”FRAN”,
        ”mail”: ”anderson@me.om”
    }
    "created_at": "2015-03-14",
    "is_purchased": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it has errors.  Use the JSON lint checker at http://jsonlint.com  copy and paste your data.

```
Parse error on line 4:
...      {            ”id”: 3,           
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the keys had angled quotes like in ”id”. The article key had an array value but it repeated so I made that one value. If you do need multiple values then make sure to use a comma between them.  You were also missing a comma between article and user.

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "article": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "LellesBread",
            "brand": "Bear",
            "quantity": 5.243,
            "entity": "oz",
            "created_at": "2014-04-21"
    },
   "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Frans",
        "lastName": "Anderson",
        "UserName": "FRAN",
        "mail": "anderson@me.om"
    },
    "created_at": "2015-03-14",
    "is_purchased": "true"
}
```